# Wordpress Blog Post are not displaying in custum theme

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woothemes

I am working on a Woocommerce site, and i am using Mystile(customize) theme for it. I added a page name Blog and want to show all the post here, how do i do this. I am not using static pages so  Setting -> Reading will not work for me. I also tried Page Attribute 'Blog'(template-blog.php a default file in Mystile theme)but it's not work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through the posts:

```
if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

Then print the articles in the format you want..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using WordPress Loop?? 
https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop